# Split the column value and make key as column name in postgres query

Tags: postgresql, split

I have the table with the column value as below:

```
data_as_of_date:20210202 unique_cc:3999
data_as_of_date:20220202 unique_cc:1999
```

i need to convert this column into like this:

```
data_as_of_date    unique_cc
20210202           3999
20220202           1999
```

Sample data:

```
create table test (val varchar); 
insert into test(val) values ('data_as_of_date:20210202 unique_cc:3999'); 
insert into test(val) values ('data_as_of_date:20220202 unique_cc:1999');
```

I have tried with unnest with string_to_array & crosstab functions, but it is not working.

Comment: Hi the test data is :create table test (val varchar);

insert into test(val) values ('data_as_of_date:20210202 unique_cc:3999');
insert into test(val) values ('data_as_of_date:20220202 unique_cc:1999');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need unnest or a crosstab for this. A simple regular expression should do the trick:

```
select substring(the_column from 'data_as_of_date:([0-9]{8})') as data_as_of_date,
       substring(the_column from 'unique_cc:([0-9]{4})') as unqiue_cc
from the_table;
```

Comment: For this query can we have dynamical headers without having to hardcode ..can we take column names from before : (colon) value.Is it possible to have dynamic column names

Comment: @user2992777: no, that's not possible.

Comment: 'data_as_of_date:([0-9]{8}).if it contains more than 8 characters in the column data_as_of_date then how to specify the pattern?can u please suggest...for example if a column contains 20 characters then how should we specify? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @user2992777: e.g. `{8,}` for "8 or more" https://regextutorial.org/

Comment: If we want dynamical headers..is it possible using stored procedure?